# How to add sick_tim551 to rviz and visualize the scan?

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

branch: turtlebot (hydro);
platform: ubuntu 12.04;
package:  [ros-hydro-sick_tim](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim)

When I use the normal camera options I could visualize the RobotModel and the camera data correctly in RViz. Until I start the command *roslaunch sick_tim 551_2050001.launch* causes the RobotModel a status Error. What I have further to do to start laser scanner correctly? Do I have to start some other packages?

[picture from error](http://www11.pic-upload.de/19.05.15/8afhox9infhs.png)

Greetings HSKA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209509/how-to-add-sick_tim551-to-rviz-and-visualize-the-scan?/) by [HSKA](https://answers.ros.org/users/21390/hska/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no link called `base_footprint` in your URDF, so you need to select either `laser` or `laser_mount_link` as the fixed frame in RViz. Usually, you would create an URDF for your robot (which would include a `base_footprint` link) and include the laser scanner URDF from there. Have a look at the [Calvin robot URDF](https://github.com/uos/calvin_robot/blob/878f3100082702dd7a82bb50c2674c1742ac4558/calvin_description/robots/calvin.urdf.xacro) and the [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HSKA](https://answers.ros.org/users/21390/hska/) on 2015-05-21**:
Thank you, it works!